# Why does this source code work?

Tags: python, properties

Some source code is like below:

```
class Flask(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def _get(self):
        return self.value
    def _set(self,value):
        self.value = value
    name = property(_get, _set)
    del _get, _set
app = Flask('abc')
app.name = 'hello'
```

My question is why this source code block can work. Class method _get, _set was deleted by `del` sentences. Why we also can use app.name to call the `Flask._set` method?

Comment: was it really deleted? since something has a reference on it, `del` could do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

`del` deletes the *name* and the memory if nothing else references it.

Since you copied the reference when doing `name = property(_get, _set)`, `del` has not the effect you're believing it has (imaging the disastrous effects of a forced deletion, for instance in a C++ code. That would make the python runtime unstable)

You cannot access `_get` and `_set` methods directly (by name), but they're still referenced somewhere.

Small, simpler example:

```
l=[3,4,5]
x=l
del l
print(x)
print(l)
```

result:

```
[3, 4, 5]    # <== x is valid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "L:\module1.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(l)
NameError: name 'l' is not defined
```

you see that `x` has kept the data. But accessing `l` raises `NameError`

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says, they're not really deleted as there are references to them (held by the property) but they (as names) are removed from the class itself, therefore writing

```
app = Flask('abc')
app._get()
app._set('foo')
```

is not possible because Flask class no longer has these members.